# How I can connect with token URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

how to authenticate a user without typing a name and password, but a URL sent by email with a token ?

I tried with a controller intercepting the url containing the token but my spring setting returns the login page because the user is anonymous.

I would also like to connect with token in the URL such as :

```
http://myWebSite/guest/18f1ff9a-fd1e-49be-bb31 ...
```

I have a token for each user in database

I have allowed anonymous access to the controller with token. Then I get the username and password of a user by token Like this :

`String queryFindUserByToken = "from UserEntity u where u.token = :token";`

Now I want to automatically create a user session with the login and password that I got from the database.

I tried to redirect to redirect to j_spring_security_check with parameters but authentication method not supported: GET

```
@RequestMapping(value = "guest/{tokenUser}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String guest(Map<String, Object> map, @PathVariable String tokenUser) {


        UserEntity user = userService.findUserByToken(tokenUser);

        return "redirect:j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + user.getUsername() + "&j_password=" + user.getPassword() ;


    }
```

do you have a better solution ?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: you mean you have to `login` with passing `username/password` in url?

Comment: can you please rephrase your question? its really hard to understand.

Comment: you have to make such url accessible to anonymous through security filter delegation

Comment: Sorry, I rephrase my question

Comment: You want a one-time token encoded in the URL that allows login?

Comment: You should implement your own authentication processing filter.

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: I tried with FlashAttribute, that not work.